# Quelles expressions françaises avec 'de' sont fixes ?

Tags: expressions

Par exemple, dans l'expression 'à côté de', le 'de' peut devenir 'du/de la/des', mais dans l'expression 'beaucoup de', le 'de' ne peut jamais les faire. Donc y a-t-il une liste avec tous ces expressions avec 'de' où le 'de' ne change pas, alors dans tous les autres, il peut changer?

(Répondez-moi en anglais, s'il vous plait).

Comment: Actually, even 'beaucoup de' uses the contracted forms 'du/des...' like in "beaucoup des gens présents..." (a lot of the people there), "beaucoup d'autres" (a lot of others), "beaucoup du pouvoir qu'il a..." (a large part of the power he has).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only rule is that *de* combines with the **articles** *le* and *les*.

---

#### Normal articles

If an article is present, *de* will combine with it:

> Les ours mangent. *The bears are eating.*
>
> **Des** ours mangent. *Some bears are eating.*

---

#### Beaucoup de

This is true after *beaucoup* as well. But *beaucoup* with and without an article mean different things:

> Je vois beaucoup **de** lapins. *I see a lot of rabbits.*
>
> Je vois beaucoup **des** lapins. *I see a lot of **the** rabbits (that we were talking about earlier).*

---

#### Apostrophe combinations

Also, apostrophe combinations always take precedence over *de* combinations. Here we get *du* :

> Le temps est venu. *The time has come.*
>   
> Beaucoup **du** temps. *Much of the time.*

But here we don't, because the *l'* is more important:

> L'ami de Marie parle beaucoup. *Marie's friend talks a lot.*
>   
> Je parle **de l**'ami de Marie. *I'm talking about Marie's friend.*

---

#### Direct objects

There is one common kind of sentence where you don't get a combination. It's when *le* and *les* aren't articles, but direct objects of a verb: *le* as in "him" or "it" and *les* as in "them".

> A-t-il déménagé ? *Did he move away?*
>   
> Non, je continue **de le** voir de temps en temps. *No, I continue to see **him** from time to time.*
>
> Les enfants sont-ils bien contents ? *Are the children quite happy?*
>   
> Oui, leur grand-mère s'efforce **de les** gâter ! *Yes, their grandma is doing her best to spoil **them**!*

---

#### à + le, les

Luckily, all of the above rules also apply to *à* combinations.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for clearing all of it up. To confirm, it's all contextual to the sentence as to the changing of the 'de', right?

Comment: Yup. You just ask yourself: "Does this *le* mean *the* or *it* or *him*?" If it means *the*, combine. If it mean *it* or *him*, don't.

Comment: Concerning your _Apostrophe combinations_ section, I feel it would have been simpler to mention that _de le_ & _de les_ are to be contracted to _du, des_, while _de la_ and _de l'_ are to remain as is. Maybe just a native speaker bias, though...

Comment: I've seen a few learners' books mention that, and indeed generally treat it like there are four articles: *le*, *la*, *les*, and *l'* ! Personally, I'd rather just keep three articles in mind and remember that they can combine. I consider it a more elegant linguistic taxonomy — fewer entries and more rules. ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Beaucoup de* refers to a large quantity. In your context, it can be replaced by *Un grand nombre de*.

But you are wrong when saying *Beaucoup de*s does not exist.

> **Beaucoup des** miens habitent encore dans les oasis.
>
> **Beaucoup des** nôtres sont allés travailler à l'étranger.

[Examples source](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-92176.php)

---

You can use *beaucoup des* when you talk about all the beings or things we talk about.

> J'ai attrapé **beaucoup de** poissons.
>
> **Beaucoup des** poissons que j'ai attrapés sont encore petits.

Before a personal pronoun, you can use *beaucoup de*

> J'ai **beaucoup de** chance.

Comment: Ok, I was misinformed. Is there any expression then where the 'de' remains fixed regardless of context, and what about certain verbs that are followed by 'a' like penser + a? Is that 'a' fixed?

Comment: I would say no. I don't have any verb in mind that respect your condition. Regarding "penser", you can say "***penser à** quelqu'un*", "[***penser des** pensées de paix*](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/auteur/bossuet/14)", "[*on **pense en** me faisant injure*](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/auteur/moliere/98)"

Answer (score 2):

That's a great question!

As a native French speaker, I actually never thought about it and I guess I just learned all of the special cases by heart without noticing. However, from your perspective, I can totally understand that it seems a bit confusing.

I don't have any formal answer to offer you, but I can maybe give you a good heuristic to help you understand in which situations you should use each type of expressions.

**Here we go:**

The expressions `beaucoup de..`, `énormément de..` or `un peu de..` are used for the times you would say `a lot of..`, `a bit of..`, `tons of..` in English.

However, `de` can become `du` or `des` when, in English, you would use `the` instead of `of`, like in `beside the cat` -> `à côté du chat`.

So as a rule of thumb, in a lot of contexts, `of` = `de`, and `"de"` becomes invariant, but every time you use `"the"`, to translate in French, your `de` can become `de`, `du`, `des`, `de la`.

I hope this gives you a bit of intuition about when to use each form.